# Serialize JSON with a python keyword using the django-rest-framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a django app (using the django-rest-framework) that needs to serialize and deserialize JSON payloads with the python keyword "import" as one of the fields. To prevent conflicts in the model, I can call the field `import_flag` and use the `source` option in the ModelSerializer.

**models.py**

```py
class MyModel(model.Model):
    import_flag = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Import')
```

But (for obvious reasons) I cannot  use the `import` keyword as to create a JSON field named "import" like so.

**serializers.py**

```py
    class MyModelSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
        import = serializers.BooleanField(source='import_flag')
        
        def Meta:
            model = MyModel
```

This field is present in the JSON I consume from a third-party's RESTful API and I also need to serialize it and send it back to the same third-party.

Is there something like a `destination` option for the Django-rest-framework ModelSerializer class? I have been unable to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: For those finding this, per [Nima's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10462931/nima-afshar) answer, here's a link to the django-rest-framework [documentation on custom serialization and deserialization behavior](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by overriding `to_internal_value` and `to_representation` in your serializer.

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ...

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        instance = super(MyModelSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        instance.import_flag = data.get('import')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(MyModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data['import'] = instance.import_flag
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `to_representation` method to add extra fields when serializing back:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    attrs = super().to_representation(instance)
    attrs['import'] = attrs['import_flag']
    ...
    return attrs
```

You can also override the `__init__` of your serializer and try adding the `import` field there:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['import'] = serializers.BooleanField(source='import_flag')
```